# Is there a way to prevent the DocumentDB SDK from throwing exceptions and handle errors with status code?

Tags: c#, exception, sdk, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am currently trying my hand at the .NET DocumentDB SDK and as I went on testing I realised that trying to get a document using `DocumentClient.ReadDocumentAsync` will throw a `NotFoundException` if the document does not exist. This behaviour seems odd to me as based on the documentation every call should return a `ResourceResponse` object that has a `StatusCode` property. Has anyone been able to prevent the exceptions from being thrown with some configuration or other and rely only on the `ResourceResponse.StatusCode` property ?

Here is a code sample:

```
private IDocumentClient _documentClient = ...

// ...
public async Task<dynamic> ReadDocument(string databaseName, string collectionName, 
 string documentId, string partitionKey) {
    return await _documentClient.ReadDocumentAsync(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(
                    databaseName,
                    collectionName, 
                    documentId),
                new RequestOptions { 
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey)
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an [extension](https://github.com/ealsur/auth0documentdb/blob/master/Extensions/DocumentDbLinqExtensions.cs) for this particular case:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the first result
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the Class</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">Queryable to take one from</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T TakeOne<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    var documentQuery = source.AsDocumentQuery();            
    if (documentQuery.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var queryResult = documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>().Result;
        if (queryResult.Any())
        {
            return queryResult.Single<T>();
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

It returns the document or `null`:

```
var document = client.CreateDocumentQuery<User>("The_Collection_Uri",new FeedOptions() { MaxItemCount = 1 }).Where(x => x.id == "some_id").TakeOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies, after discussing with a colleague yesterday I eventually went for a query over the document id and partition key which allows me to retrieve the document using `FirstOrDefault` to get my document within my partition like this:

```
var result = _documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName))
                    .Where(d => d.Id == document.Id && d.PartitionKey == document.PartitionKey)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

That way I can get my document and avoid a NotFoundException if it doesn't exist, now I just do a null check.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that point reads are efficient (performance, mostly less RU's) and recommended compared to query.

CosmosClient (version V3+ onwards) do support streaming API, where response with-out de-serialization is returned back which doesn't interpret status-codes and throw Exception.

ref: [Container.ReadItemStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readitemstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Container_ReadItemStreamAsync_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_PartitionKey_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_ItemRequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)